# DNS record with two IP addresses

Tags: email, dns

I have two computers with different public IP address. On the first machine let's say it has IP 11.22.33.44 is installed apache with some site. On the second machine with IP 55.66.77.88 is installed a mail server with SMTP and IMAP. I have domain in GoDaddy (for example test.com). How can I make the record to work together, When I type in browser example.com to send the request on 11.22.33.44 and when I send the email with somename@example.com to send it  on 55.66.77.88.

The question is not complicated, but will be good to explain me why it should be make that, because I can't understand the MX and CName records.

Comment: Well, if you can’t understand what MX records are for, why are you messing with DNS? I suggest you go do some research on what record is used for which activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an A-Record (of www) that will point to the public IP of your webhost. This will make your website available for everyone.

For mail, you need to create another A-Record, that will link eg. mail.domain.com to the public IP of your mailserver. Besides that, you need to create an MX-record that points to the mail.domain.com record.

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/activate/mx_faq.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jente's answer I will advice you to check the ports of the routers 'above' the two machines you have. The specific ports for mailing should be allowed and pointed to the second machine for the emails and the http/https ports should be allowed and pointed to the apache server machine.